# How to create a git remote?

Tags: git, git-remote

I'm not talking about `git remote add`, I'm talking about actually creating *"the remote"*, like one on GitHub, the one you have to add with `git remote add`. From what I know a remote is just another copy of a repo, but it's stored on some dedicated machine. I want to try hosting something like that on my local network, so I can have bootleg GitHub at home. Is it possible?

Comment: You run `git init` on the remote server.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use a folder (with a git repo in it) as a remote.
So if you already have a shared network folder in your local network (that's mounted into your local filesystem), you could just copy your git repos there and add them as remotes. (On Linux anyway. Windows file shares might be too slow/buggy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, what you are looking for is a Git "server".

The double quotes are, as others mentioned it as well, because Git doesn't really require an instance running as a server. Every Git repository is a "server" you can clone.

However, if you search for "run git server locally" in Google, you'll find plenty of results.

Referencing some of the steps from one easy [example](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/how-run-your-own-git-server/):

- Install git on the machine: `sudo apt-get install git-core`
- Create a dir for the repo: `mkdir -p $HOME/project-1.git`
- Go to that dir: `cd $HOME/project-1.git`
- Initialize the repo: `git init --bare`
- Add the repo as a remote: `git remote add origin ssh://git@remote-server/<path>`

Answer (score 4):

Git doesn't even need a dedicated "server" when working over SSH.

If you have shell access and appropriate permissions, you can run `git init --bare` in an empty directory to turn it into a Git repository. Then you can add `username@hostname:path/to/dir` as a Git remote and do your normal pulls and pushes, leveraging your normal SSH access, including any host aliases and config defined in `~/.ssh/config`.

If you're only looking to storing your code on a remote server this is the easiest way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The remote concept of git actually refers to **any** remote repository, it doesn't need to be some kind of specific server.
So if you just create a repo locally on your machine, it can be added as a remote for another git repo.